# Create a list with certain number of rows and columns in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have a problem I can't seem to get right.

I have 2 numbers, A & B.  I need to make a list of A rows with B columns, and have them print out 'R0CO', 'R0C1', etc.

Code:

```
import sys

A= int(sys.argv[1])

B= int(sys.argv[2])

newlist = []
row = A
col = B
for x in range (0, row): 
  newlist.append(['R0C' + str(x)])

  for y in range(0, col):
    newlist[x].append('R1C' + str(y))

print(newlist)
```

This is not working.  The following is the output I get and the expected output: 
Program Output

Program Failed for Input: 2 3
Expected Output:

```
[['R0C0', 'R0C1', 'R0C2'], ['R1C0', 'R1C1', 'R1C2']]
```

Your Program Output:

```
[['R0C0', 'R1C0', 'R1C1', 'R1C2'], ['R0C1', 'R1C0', 'R1C1', 'R1C2']]
```

Your output was incorrect. Try again

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, Patrick.  I have only been programming for three weeks, and just joined this site the other day.  Still learning.

Comment: You should be appending in only one place, the innermost for loop.  You should also be making the row numbers in the strings programmatically, not hardcoding `R0C`. Look at [this page](https://pyformat.info/) for some techniques for formatting python strings

Comment: @PatrickHaugh They still need to append a new list on each iteration of the outer loop, though

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels Good point. Maybe better to say that the strings should only be added in the innermost loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are first adding `R0Cx` and then `R1Cxy`. You need to add `RxCy`. So try:

```
newlist = []
row = A
col = B
for x in range (0, row): 
  newlist.append([])

  for y in range(0, col):
    newlist[x].append('R' + str(x) + 'C' + str(y))

print(newlist)
```

Comment: Perfect!! I was getting close, but just saw this.  Can you explain real quick why we use empty brackets for the first append?

Comment: It‘s for adding an empty array you can fill in the second loop. Otherwise you would have nothing to fill.

Comment: Got it.  I figured it out after thinking about it, but thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your range commands as shown:

```
for x in range (row): 
  for y in range(col):
```

In fact, you have a second issue that you are not modifying the text properly:

```
newlist = []
row = A
col = B
for x in range (row):   
    sublist = []
    for y in range(col):
        sublist.append('R{}C{}'.format(x, y))
    newlist.append(sublist)
```

Comment: This way is obviously cleaner, but functionally identical.

Comment: That's true, the real issue is with the way you are looping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill columns in a row while still in that row:

```
rows = []
row = 2
col = 3

for x in range(0, row):
    columns = []
    for y in range(0, col):
        columns.append('R' + str(x) + 'C' + str(y))

    rows.append(columns)


print(rows)
```

will print:

`[['R0C0', 'R0C1', 'R0C2'], ['R1C0', 'R1C1', 'R1C2']]`